# Item Changed Alert Email Modification

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, alert, custom-alert-templates

I have users who have set up alerts on lists in SharePoint O365.  It has been requested multiple times that I change this default alert template.  Specifically the grayed out strikethrough text, they want it highlighted instead.

How can I add styles this default alert email in O365 SharePoint?  In 2010 I could have modified the alerttemplates.xml file, but I don't know how to get that in O365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you can't.

Your only other recourse is to create a on change workflow that emails out something you craft yourself instead of using alerts.

Comment: It's a hosted service, so don't expect the same flexibility that you had on premises. Having said that, you could always submit something on uservoice, https://sharepoint.uservoice.com.